# How to apply a function between the elements of 2 lists in R?

Tags: r, list, functional-programming

Imagine that you have these variables:

```
> a <- list(matrix(1:25, 5, 5, byrow = TRUE), matrix(31:55, 5, 5, byrow = TRUE))
> b <- list(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))
> a
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    6    7    8    9   10
[3,]   11   12   13   14   15
[4,]   16   17   18   19   20
[5,]   21   22   23   24   25

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   31   32   33   34   35
[2,]   36   37   38   39   40
[3,]   41   42   43   44   45
[4,]   46   47   48   49   50
[5,]   51   52   53   54   55

> b
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
```

I want to end up with something like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    6    7    8    9   10
[4,]   11   12   13   14   15
[5,]   16   17   18   19   20
[6,]   21   22   23   24   25

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2
[2,]   31   32   33   34   35
[3,]   36   37   38   39   40
[4,]   41   42   43   44   45
[5,]   46   47   48   49   50
[6,]   51   52   53   54   55
```

So, it is like having a Python `zip`-like function and then apply `rbind`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(rbind, b, a)
```

Comment: I have to accept this one for an answer for its compact form.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try:

```
lapply(1:length(a),function(i)rbind(b[[i]],a[[i]]))
```

Assuming length(a) == length(b)

Comment: You might want to change the order of the arguments in `rbind()` to end up with the output given as example. (`rbind(b[[i]],a[[i]])` to have elements of `b` on top)

Comment: I like the trick to iterate over `length(a)` in `lapply(1:length(a)....`. Nice one!

Comment: Thanks. Sadly though, there are times in python, i end up using this instead of zip lol

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `purrr` package.

```
library(purrr)

map2(b, a, rbind)
```