# merging lists of dataframes in R effectively

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 12 sets of 4 lists that contain between 2 to 13 data frames
I want to merge them into 1 set of 4 lists of data frames.

While I call them sets, they are simply stored in Global Environment as:
list_a_1,
list_b_1,
list_c_1,
list_d_1,
list_a_2,
list_b_2,
list_c_2,
list_d_2,
...

list_a_1 ~ list_a_12 would have data frames that have the exact same names and same columns.

My desired outcome is 4 lists containing all 12 sets of dataframe merged.

```
df1 = data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 100:104)
df2 = data.frame(C = 6:10, D = 100:104)

list_a_1 = list(df1, df2)
list_a_2 = list(df1, df2)



desired_outcome
df1
   A   B
1  1 100
2  2 101
3  3 102
4  4 103
5  5 104
6  1 100
7  2 101
8  3 102
9  4 103
10 5 104

df2
    C   D
1   6 100
2   7 101
3   8 102
4   9 103
5  10 104
6   6 100
7   7 101
8   8 102
9   9 103
10 10 104
```

I tried writing a function with rbind, append, merge ... etc. with an aim to use it with lapply, but cannot seem to get it right.
Since each list is quite large, efficiency is also an important factor.

Comment: So you want to `rbind` `list_a_1[[1]]`, `list_a_2[[1]]` , `list_a_3[[1]]` and so on. Similarly , `list_a_1[[2]]`, `list_a_2[[2]]` and same for `list_b` , `list_c` and `list_d` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a function between the elements of 2 lists in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654257/how-to-apply-a-function-between-the-elements-of-2-lists-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are correspoinding elements to be `rbind`, use `Map` in `base R`

```
Map(rbind, list_a_1, list_a_2)
#[[1]]
#   A   B
#1  1 100
#2  2 101
#3  3 102
#4  4 103
#5  5 104
#6  1 100
#7  2 101
#8  3 102
#9  4 103
#10 5 104

#[[2]]
#    C   D
#1   6 100
#2   7 101
#3   8 102
#4   9 103
#5  10 104
#6   6 100
#7   7 101
#8   8 102
#9   9 103
#10 10 104
```

Or loop over the sequence of one `list`, extract each based on the index and `rbind`

```
lapply(seq_along(list_a_1), function(i) rbind(list_a_1[[i]], list_a_2[[i]]))
```

---

For multiple `lists`, we can use

```
v1 <- paste0('list_', letters[1:4], "_", rep(1:2, each = 4))
```

and then use `mget`

```
lst1 <- mget(v1)
```

Or this can be done automatically with a regex pattern

```
list_b_1 <- list_a_1
list_b_2 <- list_a_2
list_c_1 <- list_a_1
list_c_2 <- list_a_2
list_d_1 <- list_a_1
list_d_2 <- list_a_2
nms <- ls(pattern = '^list_[a-d]_\\d+$')
lst1 <- mget(nms)
grps <- sub("list_([a-d])_\\d+", "\\1", nms)
lst2 <- split(lst1, grps)
out <- lapply(lst2, function(lstnew) do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, unname(lstnew))))
```

-checking the output

```
out$a
[[1]]
   A   B
1  1 100
2  2 101
3  3 102
4  4 103
5  5 104
6  1 100
7  2 101
8  3 102
9  4 103
10 5 104

[[2]]
    C   D
1   6 100
2   7 101
3   8 102
4   9 103
5  10 104
6   6 100
7   7 101
8   8 102
9   9 103
10 10 104
```

For 'd' objects

```
out$d
[[1]]
   A   B
1  1 100
2  2 101
3  3 102
4  4 103
5  5 104
6  1 100
7  2 101
8  3 102
9  4 103
10 5 104

[[2]]
    C   D
1   6 100
2   7 101
3   8 102
4   9 103
5  10 104
6   6 100
7   7 101
8   8 102
9   9 103
10 10 104
```

---

Or `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map2(list_a_1, list_a_2, bind_rows)
```

Comment: Thank you! The following code worked well: `out <- lapply(lst2, function(lstnew) do.call(Map, c(f = rbind, unname(lstnew))))`  Although, because of the memory shortage, I had to do one set a time, it was really helpful!