# how to bind lists in R

Tags: r, list, bind

If I have a list of data frames like this:

```
[[First]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009 35

[[Second]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009  6

[[Third]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009  21
```

and a second one:

```
[[First]]
    y  sum_1
1 2010 18
  
[[Second]]
    y  sum_1
1 2010  12

[[Third]]
    y  sum_1
1 2010  7
```

How can I bind them and obtain a list like this: ?

```
[[First]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009 35
2 2010 18
  
[[Second]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009  6
2 2010  12

[[Third]]
    y  sum_1
1 2009 21
2 2010  7
```

Do you have any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/63838635/5325862 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58654257/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `rbind` list element wise

```
Map(rbind, list1, list2)
```

With `purrr::map2` :

```
purrr::map2(list1, list2, rbind)
```

Comment: It looks like `Map()` is just a wrapper for `mapply()` with `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, so that's something to also look into